# Simple VBA script to flag transactions over $4000 that follow a pattern

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a simple script that compares and flags similar transactions (rows) and pastes them at the bottom of the sheet. The transactions which are to be flagged should meet the following criteria.

The $amount in the transactions is greater than 4000 or less than -4000 (column 11)
The two transactions being compared have the same part number (column 3)
Two transactions with similar dollar amounts (between 90-110% of each other) and opposite in number sign

```
Sub checktrans()

Dim newLastRow, rowcount As Long
Dim row, row2, amountcol, partnumcolcol As Integer

amountcol = 16
partnumcol = 3
rowcount = 27307
newLastRow = 37309

For row = 1 To rowcount

    For row2 = 1 To rowcount

      If Cells(row, amountcol) > 4000 Or Cells(row, amountcol) < -4000 Then

        If row <> row2 Then

           If Cells(row, partnumcol) = Cells(row2, partnumcol) Then

                If Abs(Cells(row, amountcol)) > 0.9 * Abs(Cells(row2, amountcol)) And Abs(Cells(row, amountcol)) < 1.1 * Abs(Cells(row2, amountcol)) Then

                 If (Cells(row, amountcol) < 0 And Cells(row2, amountcol) > 0) Or (Cells(row, amountcol) > 0 And Cells(row2, amountcol) < 0) Then

                   ActiveSheet.Rows(row).Copy
                    ActiveSheet.Rows(newLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                    newLastRow = newLastRow + 1

                    ActiveSheet.Rows(row2).Copy
                    ActiveSheet.Rows(newLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                    newLastRow = newLastRow + 1

                 End If
                End If

           End If

        End If
     End If
    Next row2

Next row

End Sub
```

I wrote the code above, and it seems to work for a low number of rows (below 500), but when the number of rows exceeds 27000 it goes into a never ending loop that keeps pasting new rows onto the sheet. It also posts each couple of transactions twice, which I understand is flaw in the logic which I have to work out as well.

P.S I am a giant noob when it comes to this, haven't programmed much before, and I'm just learning now to make my life easier.

Comment: Sounds like you could set your data up with some helper columns for your conditions and then use a pivottable for this.

Comment: A couple of items to point out.  1.  `Dim row, row2, amountcol, partnumcolcol As Integer` is only defining partnumcolcol as an integer.  2.  Instead of defining the last row as a number, I would let excel calculate the last row in the range.

Comment: I dont know how you could compare multiple rows with each other using pivot tables.                                                                                                                     @ Zack E thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you can do is to start second loop from the point where first loop is currently. Like `For row2 = row + 1 to rowcount`. You checked previous records already. This will also fix problem with duplicates and you can delete `If row <> row2`.

Second, is to use `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the beginning of the macro and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end. This turns off screen updating while your macro is running and can be a huge improvement in performance.

At the end you can join all `If`s into one using `And`, however I don't know if this will improve performance.